# creating loop in downloading files

Tags: r

My purpose is to download each of the files from EDGAR website, parse them, and write them in .txt file. 
Update: Here is the code snippet:

```
How do I create a loop so that x will be replaced by integers e.g. 1, 2, 3,.. and I can manage downloading the files? Thanks,
```

Comment: What do you mean 'it does not work'?

Comment: keeping 'x' in the gives me no results. But if I replace x by a number, say 1, it downloaded the file and parsed.

Comment: Try to narrow down your question - creating a **short** and **reproducible** example will help. Good luck!

Comment: Hi, I have shortened the query. Hope it is now easy to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would the following get you where you want to be? Note that `seq_along(masterIndex$EDGAR_LINK)` is equivalent to saying `1:length(masterIndex$EDGAR_LINK)`. So in other words, this loop will run `autoparse()` where `x` is 1, then 2, then 3, and so on, up to the length of `masterIndex$EDGAR_LINK` or wherever you want it to stop.

```
for(i in seq_along(masterIndex$EDGAR_LINK)){
  autoparse(i)
}
```